# python sqlacademy query filter

Tags: python, filter

I am having some trouble with sqlacademy in Python. I am trying to filter a record in a database.

period_filter and process_filter are passed as arguments to this function.

This gives me one record. The one that I expect:

```
    for x in session.query(ProcessStatus).filter(ProcessStatus.reporting_period == period_filter and 
     ProcessStatus.process_name == process_filter):
        print(x.id, x.process_name)
```

This gives me an error saying there i more than one record:

```
    id_to_update = session.query(ProcessStatus).filter(ProcessStatus.reporting_period == period_filter 
     and ProcessStatus.process_name == process_filter).one()
```

I tried using the last approach to update a record in database, but I updated an incorrect record (I used .first()  and not .one() in that case), as I knew only one record should satisfy both filter conditions.

I would prefer the last approach as I would like to store the object in a variable directly, as I need to  pass it to another function.

Comment: Can you clarify the problem?  Perhaps you could provide an [mre] (including sample data) that demonstrates it.

Comment: .one()  expect there should be one record in the data base,  use .first() if there is multiple records. Also user chain of filters

Comment: I was able to solve this. It seems that sqlalchemy does not accept the 'and' operator. Instead I should use the syntax:   and_(filter_1 , filter_2)

Still not sure why it seem I was able to get the correct result using the 'and' operator in the for loop.